# Bash error redirection creating file when there is no error

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to stop a service using using bash script and redirect error to a file

`service ssh stop 2> ssh.error`

The problem is the error file is created even when there is no error

Comment: this is normal behaviour. delete the file if it's empty. or simply ignore it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell must provide the command with a file that is ready for writing, which means it must open the file (creating it if necessary) before starting the command. One option is to use a separate process that reads from the command's standard error and only writes to the file if it gets some input.

```
mkfifo err
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >> ssh.error
done < err & log_pid=$!
service ssh stop 2> err
kill "$log_pid"
rm err
```

This is less efficient than simply removing the empty file.

Answer (score 2):

Shell redirection doesn't know anything about the command you are running (it may or may not even exist). The redirection (and file creation) happen **before** the command is run.

This is why you cannot read from and write to a single file using redirections. (i.e. `printf 'contents\ncontents\n' > file; more file > file` truncates/empties the `file` file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the file if it is empty

```
 service ssh stop 2> ssh.error && [[ ! -s ssh.error ]] && rm ssh.error
```